# Using ford fulkerson to place N employees in M positions with roles

Tags: php, algorithm, ford-fulkerson

I'm trying to solve a mathematical problem using Ford-Fulkerson, but I have some problems.

This is the problem

```
    I have a list of employees (Jack, John, Al, ...).
    I have a list of roles (R1, R2, R3, ...).
    I have a list of working positions (W1, W2, W3, ...).

    Every employee has a set of roles, like Jack has R1 and R2, ...
    Every working position has a set of roles that can support,
    like to work in position W1 you need R1 or R2, ...
```

I need to find the best configuration of employees - working positions, to be sure that every working position has an employee with the right roles to work there (one employee per position).

I tried using this algorithm http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/

I built a matrix where I have a row for every employee and a column for every working position. I put in the X row, Y column the value 1 if the X employee can work in the Y position, otherwise I put 0.

The algorithm above, rewritten in PHP, works great until the number of employees <= the number of positions.

If I have more employees than positions, the algorithm calculation time tends to diverge to infinite.

Here is the algorithm code:

```
function maxMatch($matrix, $cols) {
    $match = array();
    foreach ($cols as $v => $item) {
        $match[$item] = -1;
    }
    $result = 0;
    foreach ($matrix as $u => $row) {
        $seen = array();
        foreach ($cols as $v => $item) {
            $seen[$item] = 0;
        }
        if ($this->checkVertex($matrix, $u, $seen, $match)) {
            print_r($match);
            $result++;
        }
    }
    return $match;
}

function checkVertex($matrix, $u, $seen, &$match) {
    foreach ($matrix[$u] as $v => $row) {
        if ($matrix[$u][$v] && !$seen[$v]) {
            $seen[$v] = TRUE;
            if ($match[$v] < 0 || $this->checkVertex($matrix, $match[$v], $seen, $match)) {
                $match[$v] = $u;
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Everything is like the algorithm in the link above, except that I pass the $cols array, containing the indexes of the columns (because they are position IDs and not numeric ordered).

This is how I create the matrix:

```
function createMatrix($year, $month, $day, $shift) {
    global $sql;

    $result = $sql->query("VERY HUGE SELECT FOR EMPLOYEES AND POSITIONS MATCH");

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $matrix[$row['employee']][$row['position']] = 1;
    }
    return $matrix;
}
```

so I put 1 only where I have a match between employees and positions.

Anyone has any clue on how to resolve the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put in your code also? and explain how do you build the matrix?(I assume that you will have a source node and and end node, so how do you define the cost for each of them) :)

Comment: Ok I'm editing with the code, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `seen` by value. It is not correct. It should be passed by reference. What you have now is actually some kind of backtracking(the original algorithm time complexity proof is based on a fact that each vertex can be visited at most once during the depth-first-search and it is not true in your current implementation). That's why it works slow. Passing `seen` by reference should fix it.

Comment: You are right! Now it works perfectly. Thanks so much for Your help, I really appreciated it. You saved my day ;)